# Mist pass causing some transparent textures to loose transparency

Tags: error, compositing-nodes

I am trying to add a little bit of fog or something without using volumetrics, so I am trying to use a mist pass to create this effect.

[image]
This is the picture I want to add fog to

But the mist pass has removed the transparency from some of the elements on one of my particle systems.

[image: The white stuff on the floor is not welcome]

The white stuff on the floor is not welcome

The depth pass just gives me a white screen as well.
[image]

I'm not sure if anyone else has had the same problem, but I couldn't find anything similar when I looked it up.

Here is the tutorial I was following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o12B0QJ8B8I

[image]
This is the result of combining the mist pass, and while it looks alright for a snow scene, I am not going for a snow scene.

Comment: Is this EEVEE? That may be causing a malfunction, blend methods and all.

Comment: No, I am not using EEVEE. I have been having problems with optix, if that might be a contributing factor, but I am also not using optix. My optix problem is that using optix in anyway (rendering or denoising) causes Blender to fully crash.

Comment: ok. No, I don’t think that is related.

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue: [link](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/is-this-a-bug-weird-noise-in-the-mist-pass-also-on-zdepth-pass/9209) In my case, changing transparency maps to 100% opaque (white) or 100% transparent (black), nothing in between, no grayscales, solved the issue.